# How to store a value from a link button and assign it to a text box on another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a cinema project and I'm stuck at this: I want,when I click on a specific hour, to show me the reservation page and to autocomplete the hour textbox with that specific hour and the name of the movie also.

Here is the code I have and a screenshot:

```
ArrayList difuzList = new ArrayList();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        difuzList = Conectare.GetZi("%");
    }
    else
    {
        difuzList = Conectare.GetZi(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Difuzare difuzare in difuzList)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format(@"<table class='filmTabel1'>
        <tr>
              <td><a runat='server' id='numeFil'>{0}</a></td>
              <td><a runat='server' id='oraD1' href='Rezervari.aspx'>{1}</a></td>
              <td><a runat='server' id='oraD2' href='Rezervari.aspx'>{2}</a></td>
              <td><a runat='server' id='oraD3' href='Rezervari.aspx'>{3}</a></td>
              <td><a runat='server' id='oraD4' href='Rezervari.aspx'>{4}</a></td>
        </tr>

    </table>", difuzare.Nume_film,difuzare.Ora1, difuzare.Ora2, difuzare.Ora3, difuzare.Ora4));
        labeloutPr.Text = sb.ToString();

    }
```

[Hour schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyFWm.png)

[This is the reservation page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4GKG.png)

Comment: What is going wrong with what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
ArrayList difuzList = new ArrayList();

if (!IsPostBack)
{
    difuzList = Conectare.GetZi("%");
}
else
{
    difuzList = Conectare.GetZi(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Difuzare difuzare in difuzList)
{
    sb.Append(string.Format(@"<table class='filmTabel1'>
    <tr>
          <td><a runat='server' id='numeFil'>{0}</a></td>
          <td><a runat='server' id='oraD1' href='Rezervari.aspx?hour={1}'>{1}</a></td>
          <td><a runat='server' id='oraD2' href='Rezervari.aspx?hour={2}'>{2}</a></td>
          <td><a runat='server' id='oraD3' href='Rezervari.aspx?hour={3}'>{3}</a></td>
          <td><a runat='server' id='oraD4' href='Rezervari.aspx?hour={4}'>{4}</a></td>
    </tr>

</table>", difuzare.Nume_film,difuzare.Ora1, difuzare.Ora2, difuzare.Ora3, difuzare.Ora4));
    labeloutPr.Text = sb.ToString();

}
```

And then in the reservation page you retrieve and assing your hour like this (assuming textboxHour is your textbox control) :

```
textboxHour.Text = Request.QueryString["hour"];
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful